# Getting exception on adding user in MongoDB admin

Tags: mongodb, exception, admin

I am trying to add new user in MongoDb > admin table. This is what i done

```
use admin
db.addUser("test", "test123")
```

after executing command it displayed this

```
{
    "user" : "test",
    "readOnly" : false,
    "pwd" : "2ee6cd2e57f3a5829ed694d5c367bc48",
    "_id" : ObjectId("5076beeb87a1b34978829bc5")
}

Thu Oct 11 18:13:53 uncaught exception: timed out while waiting for user authentication to replicate - database will not be fully secured until replication finishes
```

What is the reason of this error?

And where can i see my new user.

Note: I am in network, is this related to any security policy ?

Comment: `show users` in the mongo shell will show your defined users.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the exception?  It is cut off.

Comment: No exception is not cut off. It is showing 2 lines only in exception and detail and i copied same here.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if this is a filed [bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5895) that was fixed in 2.1.2.  What version of MongoDB are you running?

If you are running a compatible version, are all of your secondaries alive and healthy?  It looks like the propagation of the user auth info to a secondary timed out.

Comment: I am using MongoDb 2.2.0. I am new to MongoDB, just started learning, not yet gone through the concept of replication.

Comment: Are you running with replication, or is the MongoDB instance standalone?

Comment: I am running MangoDB instance standalone,

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your bug.  What is the command you are using to start mongod?

Comment: What happens if you restart it with the [auth](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication#SecurityandAuthentication-RunninginSecureMode%28with%5Cauthor%5CkeyFile%29) command line parameter?